# Debugger for HTML/CSS/JS in Android/IOS device browser

Tags: debugging, firebug

I have developed Lots of websites, where i use Developer tools on IE / firebug on Firefox & Chrome is also having inspect element function for Editing & Debugging. But When i started developing for Android/IOS browser i am not getting how to edit & debug.

Is there any way to do this coz, its eating lots of my effort.

Answer (score 2):

[weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/) is exactely what you are looking for!
import the library into your index.html and make it point to your local weinre server or [here](http://debug.phonegap.com/) and you'll have your device console into chrome.
pretty straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a remote debugger such as [Pony](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/08/ponydebugger-remote-debugging.html) or [using Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/remote-debugging-on-firefox-for-android/).
You can also do this with [Safari](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/) on IOS.